# issue npm install -g expo-cli with deprecated warnings

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

I can't install `expo-cli`, I've tried to run `npm audit fix --force` as suggested by terminal still got same warnings & won't install. I also tried to uninstall node js & npm (deleting all related folders & files) then install both again with the latest LTS version of node `16.13.1` & npm `8.3.0`, but still can't install it and have same warnings as below ss:

[image]

Comment: I see warnings but no errors.

Comment: @Joe oh yes sorry, what I mean by errors are the warnings. I will edit the question

Comment: not all packages stay fully up to date, and especially for something like a CLI used locally the risks to you are much less than, say, in a public server exposed to the internet

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems the issue is in git bash terminal, I used powershell and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

The global CLI is deprecated, Now you could just use local one that it installed on every newly created app.
**Usage:**
just add npx before the old command like :

> expo start

become:

> npx expo start

Comment: Refer this medium article for more information https://blog.expo.dev/the-new-expo-cli-f4250d8e3421

Answer (score 0):

The installation looks successful, albeit producing some deprecation warnings. While you should use a tool like `npm audit` to understand the risks you may be facing by using these deprecated dependencies, the installation seems to have been successful, and you can use `expo-cli` normally.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `npm install` in my project directory and then it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

First Run `npm install` and then `npm start` it will work fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Follow this expo documentation. After creating project we have to install dependencies. this npx expo start command will work.
Link : https://docs.expo.dev/tutorial/create-your-first-app/

npx create-expo-app StickerSmash && cd StickerSmash

cd StickerSmash

npx expo install react-dom react-native-web @expo/webpack-config

npx expo start